# build.sbt imports for docker commands

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-plugin

I have a build.sbt file but I am not able to figure out the role of this import `import docker.{addDockerPackage}`

Is this an open source import? I am not able to find info about it. Further down in the script it calls a method `addDockerPackage()`

I wonder if the method is in that package? Or all this is some proprietary stuff? If it is a standard import, where do I read about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sbt-native it has a Docker plugin:

http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/docker.html

Here are 4 different good example that you can run to see how it works:

https://github.com/marcuslonnberg/sbt-docker

As far as:

```
import docker.{addDockerPackage}
```

I don't think that is a package. It looks more like a helper to define something like this:

```
packageName in Docker := packageName.value
```

Comment: thanks but is the "addDockerPackage" a real package?

Comment: I don't think so. This is my best bet:

    packageName in Docker := packageName.value

http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/docker.html